# Comparing Numpy/Pandas arrays with mixed elements (string & floats)

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, comparison

I have some Numpy arrays (or equivalently Pandas dataframes as it can be easily converted to) that I wish to compare. These arrays/dataframes contain both numbers and strings.

For purely numbers I can do the following.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1.0, 2.0], [1.00001, 2.00001]])
b = np.array([[1.000001, 2.00001], [1.00001, 2.00001]])
print(np.allclose(a, b, 1e-9))
# output: False
print(np.allclose(a, b, 1e-4))
# output: True
```

With a mixed array of the following, I am getting errors.

```
c = np.array([[1.0, "Cat"], [1.00001, 2.00001]])
d = np.array([[1.000001, "Dog"], [1.00001, 2.00001]])
e = np.array([[1.000001, "Cat"], [1.00001, 2.00001]])
print(np.allclose(c, d, 1e-4))
# expected output: False on account of the string difference
print(np.allclose(c, e, 1e-4))
# expected output: True
```

I tried converting it into a Pandas dataframe hoping that the builtin testing module might do the trick.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.util import testing as pdtest
df_c = pd.DataFrame(c)
df_d = pd.DataFrame(d)
df_e = pd.DataFrame(e)
print(pdtest.assert_almost_equal(df_c, df_e, check_exact=False, check_less_precise=4))
# expected output: True as the strings match and numbers agree within tolerance.
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a way to compare arrays where numerical elements are compared with a specified tolerance while string elements are compared exactly?

EDIT: The tolerance is purely for float elements. For strings, exact match is required.

Comment: Look at `c` or `d` (i.e. `print`).  Note the `dtype`.  We should probably close this because you failed to describe the `allclose` errors, and/or attempt any followup.  But the basic issue is the `allclose`, which uses `isclose` is designed for use with numeric arrays, not string arrays.

Comment: The core test is  whether `abs(x-y)` is small enough.  That doesn't apply to arrays that have a string dtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def myequal(i,j):
    # scalar comparison function of your own design
    if isinstance(i,str):
        return i==j
    else:
        return 1e04>abs(i-j)
```

The sample arrays, as object dtype:

```
In [74]: c = np.array([[1.0, "Cat"], [1.00001, 2.00001]],object)
    ...: d = np.array([[1.000001, "Dog"], [1.00001, 2.00001]],object)
    ...: e = np.array([[1.000001, "Cat"], [1.00001, 2.00001]],object)

In [75]: c
Out[75]: 
array([[1.0, 'Cat'],
       [1.00001, 2.00001]], dtype=object)
In [76]: d
Out[76]: 
array([[1.000001, 'Dog'],
       [1.00001, 2.00001]], dtype=object)
In [77]: e
Out[77]: 
array([[1.000001, 'Cat'],
       [1.00001, 2.00001]], dtype=object)
```

Use `frompyfunc` to apply `myequal` to elements of to arrays.  Basically it takes care of broadcasted iteration

```
In [78]: f = np.frompyfunc(myequal,2,1)
In [79]: f(c,d)
Out[79]: 
array([[True, False],
       [True, True]], dtype=object)
In [80]: f(c,e)
Out[80]: 
array([[True, True],
       [True, True]], dtype=object)
```

Without `object` dtype, your arrays are string dtype, the only common dtype:

```
In [81]: np.array([[1.0, "Cat"], [1.00001, 2.00001]])
Out[81]: 
array([['1.0', 'Cat'],
       ['1.00001', '2.00001']], dtype='<U32')
```

This raises an error in `allclose/isclose` because the strings can't be tested for `np.inf`:

```
In [82]: np.isclose(_,_)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-c2e4de5fe672> in <module>()
----> 1 np.isclose(_,_)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in isclose(a, b, rtol, atol, equal_nan)
   2330     y = array(y, dtype=dt, copy=False, subok=True)
   2331 
-> 2332     xfin = isfinite(x)
   2333     yfin = isfinite(y)
   2334     if all(xfin) and all(yfin):

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

`np.isfinite` applies to numeric arrays, not string ones.